# Как с помощью PHP построить такую таблицу?

Tags: php

Нужно визуализировать дом с квартирами. Допустим есть 3х этажный дом и три подъезда, в нем 27 квартир

В итоге получить что-то типа этого
[image: В итоге получить что-то типа этого]

Есть массив данных, его нужно привести к виду, как на картинке (примерно)

$array = [
'number' => 1,
'floor' => 3,
'enters'=> 3,
'rooms' => 27
];

С HTML + CSS проблем нет. Проблема как правильно собрать массив для вывода

Да тут математика обычная:
27 квартир / 3 подъезда
Получаем 9 квартир в 1м подъезде
9 квартир / 3 этажа
Получаем 3 квартиры на этаже

А вот как сделать генерацию в 1м подъезде в таком порядке 7,8,9 - 4,5,6 - 1,2,3, не могу придумать

Comment: Добавьте пример кода.

Comment: Есть массив в PHP из него нужно собрать подобии того, что на картинке $array = [
  'number' => 1,
  'floor' => 3,
  'enters'=> 3,
  'rooms' => 27
];

Comment: А в чем затруднение? Организовать правильно цикл?

Comment: Да, не могу понять, как поделить и перевернуть данные, чтобы строилось именно три ячейки в нужном алгоритме

Comment: Мы тоже не можем понять как поделить и перевернуть ваши данные. Для навала покажите их в том виде, в каком они есть.

Comment: Чуть выше писал, есть массив в PHP. Из него нужно собрать то что на картинке

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP не предназначен для визуализации. Для этого есть html.  Для начала реализуйте это просто на html.  После этого, если вы имеете представление о массивах и циклах сгенерируйте динамическую часть страницы при помощи PHP

```
<?php
    //    $array = [ 'number' => 1, 'floor' => 3, 'enters'=> 3, 'rooms' => 27 ];
    $array = [ 'number' => 2, 'floor' => 3, 'enters'=> 2, 'rooms' => 24 ];
    $arResult = [];
    $roomsInEnter = ceil($array['rooms'] / $array['enters']);
    $roomsInFloor = ceil($roomsInEnter / $array['floor'] );
    for ($i=1;$i<=$array['rooms'];++$i)
    {
        $curEnter = ceil($i / $roomsInEnter);
        $curFloor = ceil(($i - ($curEnter-1 ) * $roomsInEnter)/ $roomsInFloor) ;
        $arResult[$array['floor']-$curFloor][] = $i;
    }
    for($i=0;$i<$array['floor'];++$i)
    {
        foreach($arResult[$i] as $room)
        {
            echo $room."\t";
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Вот как раз с циклами и вопрос, сделать на HTML+CSS нет проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо за пример! Практически то что нужно. Буду изучать!

Comment: $array = [ 'number' => 2, 'floor' => 3, 'enters'=> 2, 'rooms' => 24 ]; С таким уже не работает

Comment: А что означает number?

Comment: @denis.dc Не правильно определялся этаж. Исправил код  ответе

Comment: number -  номер дома, по сути не нужная вещь

Comment: Теперь работает!! Спасибо большое!

Comment: Скорее всего это сейчас будет выглядеть, как хамство с моей стороны, но не могли бы вы подсказать еще один момент.Все тоже самое, дом 3 этажа, только подъездов 4, квартир 30 и 2,3 подъезды всего по 6 квартир

Comment: На решение нет времени - потому только наводки.
Тут уже несколько хитрее алгоритм надо строить. Я бы фиктивно увеличил с число картир до ровного количества по подъездам, а потом в зависимости от подъезда и этажа добавлял либо пустоту либо $arResult[$array['floor']-$curFloor][] = $i - $delta;  Где $delta число "пропущеных" квартир.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз. Разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Тройной цикл - не лучшее решение, но если вызывает вопрос именно вывод в PHP - то это будет пояснением:

```
<!-- где-то в виде 
 $floors - массив этажей
 $padiki - массив массивов вида {
   'label' строка,
   'enters' число
   'rooms' массив, где ключ - этаж, значение - номер комнаты
 }
-->
<table>
<? foreach($floors as $floor){ ?>
<tr>
  <td>
     <?=$floor?>
  </td>
  <? foreach($padiki as $podezd){ ?>
     <? foreach($podezd['rooms'][$floor] as $room){ ?>
       <td>
           <?=$room?>
       </td>
     <? } ?>
  <? } ?>
</tr>
<? } ?>
<tr class="footer">
     <td></td>
<? foreach($padiki as $podezd){ ?>
      <td colspan="<?=podezd['enters']?>">
         <?=$podezd['label']?>
      </td>
<? } ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Cформировать `$floors` и `$padiki`  можно вложенным циклом по представленным исходным данным. Предлагаю автору самому это сделать.

Comment: Ой, сейчас подправлю

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать